# How can I open a web page from an Android app?

Tags: android, web, networking

I am trying to open a web page from my Android app.
This is what I did:

```
 successCallback = {
                    url-> runOnUiThread{
                    val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("$url"))
                    startActivity(browserIntent)}
                }
```

But it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

[This the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5HAg.png)

Comment: Is the url starts with `http://`.

Comment: I forgot to set a value to url. It was only " ". This is why it didn't work lol

Comment: close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your **URL** is correct or not i.e URL contain proper link or value, then parse it.

```
successCallback = {
                url-> runOnUiThread{
                if (url!= null && !url.isEmpty()){
                val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("$url"))
                startActivity(browserIntent)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
successCallback = {
                    url-> runOnUiThread {
                  Intent browserIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse ("YOUR URL") );
                    startActivity (browserIntent);
                }
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = yoururl;
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to open the page within your app? You should use a Webview or chrome custom tabs https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview